# Removing automatically added line breaks when combining Javascript + HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, line, line-breaks

Just starting off in web development and hoped one of you all could help me out.
I am building a site that displays the weather along with the four-day forecast with the help of [SimpleWeather.js](http://simpleWeatherjs.com). There's a section in my javascript where I want to display a particular day's High & Low with a "|" in the middle to divide them. I also wanted to declare a class for the "|" part so that I can change the color of the divider. However, when I do this, it adds two line breaks, and I don't understand why or how to fix it.

The code is

```
      $("#high-low-one").html(weather.forecasts.one.high+'<p class="high-low-divider">|</p>'+weather.forecasts.one.low);
```

However it shows up as:

30

|

28
 (where the 30 is the high and 28 is the low temperature for any given day.)

I've also tried fixing this in CSS using inline-text, inline-block, block, and nowrap, just to name a few. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` Is a block element by default. You can change this with CSS but use `<span>` instead as it is by default an inline element

You would end up with:

```
 $("#high-low-one").html(weather.forecasts.one.high+'<span class="high-low-divider">|</span>'+weather.forecasts.one.low);
```

However I would style the temps in `span` elements and use the `:after` [pseudo-element](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) to add and style the pipe character.

Something like:

```
$("#high-low-one").html("<span class='high'>" + weather.forecasts.one.high + "</span><span class='low'>" + weather.forecasts.one.low + "</span>");
```

With some sample css:

```
#high-low-one .high
{
    color:#F00;    
}

#high-low-one .high:after
{
    content: "|";
    color: #0F0;
    padding-left:0.5em;
    padding-right:0.5em;
}

#high-low-one .low
{
    color:#00F;    
}
```

Which would give you something like: http://jsfiddle.net/D29AH/

For Completeness if you really had to use `<p>` use the following CSS

```
.high-low-divider
{
    display:inline;
}
```